# SKStoreProductViewController error ITMLKITErrorDomain 101

Tags: ios, objective-c, storekit

In my app I show more apps with SKStoreProductViewController, but the Apple store review team rejects it with the reason:

> "An error message displays when tapping on the more apps button."

Everything works fine when I test it on my devices.

Below is the screenshot Apple sent me, what could be the problem?

[image: error]

Sample code:

```
 __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
  SKStoreProductViewController* vc = [[SKStoreProductViewController alloc] init];
  vc.delegate = self;
  [vc loadProductWithParameters:@{SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier : @1000000000} completionBlock:^(BOOL result, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if(result==NO){
      //handle failure
      return;
    }
    [weakSelf presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];

  }];
```

Comment: They typically tell you what device it failed on. Have you tested the functionality on the same device? Could be a 32/64 bit thing, or iPhone/iPad, iOS difference.

Comment: Could you add the block of code that is executed when you tap the "more apps" button? Specifically, what are the parameters being loaded? Have you deleted the app and re-installed on each device as well to test? If you don't want to delete the app, you can temporarily change the bundle id and run the app on your devices.

Comment: I've added some sample code, note replaced app identifier with 10000000

Answer (score 2):

`ITMLKitErrorDomain` errors frequently occur when a `SKStoreProductViewController` tries to call `loadProductWithParameters` with invalid parameters.  Example full error:

> ```
> <Warning>: [SKStoreProductViewController]: Did fail with error: Error Domain=ITMLKitErrorDomain Code=101 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (ITMLKitErrorDomain error 101.)" UserInfo={ ... } {ITMLKitErrorHTTPStatus=400}
> ```

Verify you do not have any typos or unexpected keys in your `parameters` dictionary when calling `loadProductWithParameters`.  Verify the values for keys such as `SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier` and `SKStoreProductParameterAffiliateToken` are valid.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not experiencing this issue on test devices, just send it to review again, this could be a temporary issue with itunes site (it is used to show these "more apps", isn't it?). There are several mentions of that problem over the internet without any solution.

Answer (score 1):

During investigation of youre issue it is possible to conclude that is quite rare case that could be connected with wrong product id in case of `SkProductViewController`. Also you should check if you are trying to show single app or amount of them. Because Apple have [bug](https://devforums.apple.com/message/951745) that is connected with showing of multiple items.

I am using SKStoreProductViewController in this way. This is code block that show app in App Store:

```
SKStoreProductViewController *storeProductViewController = [[SKStoreProductViewController alloc] init];

    [storeProductViewController setDelegate:self];
    [storeProductViewController loadProductWithParameters:@{SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier : @"xxxxx"} completionBlock:^(BOOL result, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error %@ with User Info %@.", error, [error userInfo]);

        } else {
            [self presentViewController:storeProductViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
    }];
```

Then i use delegate `SKStoreProductViewControllerDelegate` like this:

```
- (void)productViewControllerDidFinish:(SKStoreProductViewController *)viewController {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Also i use `[button setExclusiveTouch:YES];` because customers some times press few buttons with products. Also test you're id if it is single product.

Answer (score 0):

I just finished dealing with this same issue. Everything works just fine when testing the app but the App Review team was rejecting my app for showing an alert view with the error returned by the call to `loadProductWithParameters`.

I worked around the issue by launching the App Store in Safari if the call to `loadProductWithParameters` fails. This provides a useful fallback in the rare cases when `SKStoreProductViewController` isn't working.

```
SKStoreProductViewController *vc = [[SKStoreProductViewController alloc] init];
vc.delegate = self;

NSDictionary *parameters = @{ SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier : someAppId };
[vc loadProductWithParameters:parameters completionBlock:^(BOOL result, NSError *error) {
    if (result) {
        [someController presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
    } else {
        NSURL *appURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://itunes.apple.com/app/id%@?mt=8", someAppId]];
        if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:appURL]) {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:appURL];
        } else {
            // display the error in an alert
        }
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had a rejection for the same reason (2 rejections) and I've found that I get this exact error testing without Wi-Fi (on a Wi-Fi only device).

So my thought is that Apple is testing this on a Wi-Fi device (they said they are testing on a Wi-Fi iPad) and they have disabled Wi-Fi. It would be nice if in the rejection they told you about the fact that they were testing with no internet access but you need to read between the lines.

So since you can't display the controller without an internet connection you need to show an appropriate error like "Please check your internet connection and try again."

Definitely don't show the localized description for the Error returned to the user.